# Migrated Joomla Site shows Table doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, joomla

I have a joomla 2.5 site created locally on my machine, that I've migrated to a vps running nginx, php and mysql. Here is what i did in order:

```
 1. Uploaded all the joomla files in the public_html
 2. Changed all the files permission to 644 and all the folders to 755
 3. Imported the database.sql to mysql using these commands: 

--> mysql> create database databasename;    
--> mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON
databasename.* TO username@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';   
--> mysql> flush privileges;    
--> mysql> exit    
--> user@vps:~$ mysql -p -u username database_name < file.sql
```

I can see all my tables inside the database already, and changed all the needed information on my joomla `configuration.php` but when i open my site, i get this error:

```
Table 'databasename.s1t3j0s_session' doesn't exist SQL=INSERT INTO `s1t3j0s_session` (`session_id`, `client_id`, `time`) VALUES ('rh249ehb2tbsqkdff34v177d76', 0, '1357339991')
```

Where did i got it wrong?

I have migrated wordpress site to the same server with no error.

Comment: Does the session table exist? If yes, did you empty it? Repair?

Comment: I have tried repairing it already, but with no luck, i still get the same error.

Comment: You didn't answer my other two questions.

Comment: Sorry, yes the table exists, its there. But what do you mean by emptying? Do i have to remake the table manually?

Comment: Is the databasename, really supposed to be databasename? I guess not.

Comment: yeah it's not, i just changed it here before posting.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having trouble with it for weeks. What I needed was a backup copy on my system. However, when I uploaded the database from the remote server onyto my localhost I was getting error messages relating to the session table not existing (the same error that you are getting).

I tried all of the tips relating to deleting and re-creating the tables, but this did not work.

The only solution which worked 100% - which I finally discovered today, was to re-install Joomla 2.5 (I used a fresh install), and then do the following:

Instead of uploading the database from site containing the correct content, instead go through the SQL file itself (i.e. the one you will have exported for upload before encountering problems), and manually process each one of the insert statements into your SQL console directly (I'm using PHPMyadmin). In other words, don't attempt to import the whole file as you normally would. To do this will just result in errors.

For some reason, Joomla 2.5 has an issue with tables that are already populated with data being replaced by a dump file or replacement, sometimes duplicate, data. Hence the need for a fresh install....

Before processing each of the install statements individually (this can take a while - it took me about an hour and a half), go through each of the Joomla tables and make sure that NONE of them are populated with any data whatsoever (therefore when you process the install statements they will not be replacing existing data - because you will have removed all data from populated tables).

So long as you make sure that no INSERTED data has been added to the tables prior to the migration, this will solve your problem.

So to summise:
1/ Get a fresh J2.5 install.
2/ Delete all popolated table data from every joomla table.
3/ Copy and paste each of the insert statements from the exported mysql file containing the correct data. Process each statement individually (this is optional, but highly recommended: to do it this way enables you to counter and pinpoint any individual errors if and when they occur - without having to look through the entire mysql file)

...Go to your site: bingo - it should work!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the value of `$dbprefix` in `configuration.php` under the Joomla directory has the correct value by checking it against the actual db prefix used (*open phpMyAdmin and choose the Joomla database to check for this*).

Answer (score 0):

Just truncate the data in the session table and do the process again. You have nothing to worry about truncating because there are no valuable data. Session table sometimes messes up stuff.

On Unix, table names are case sensitive. On Windows, they are not. Fun, isn't it? Kinda like their respective file systems. Do you think it's a coincidence?

Caveat: it probably depends on table type; MyISAM.

Field names are case-insensitive regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, 
in my case, I imported the database through the cpanel and later on got this error message. I later found out that importing database through the cpanel didnot import the tables, just the database name. So I went to the phpmyadmin and import the database there once again, and solved.