# Error displaying the error page in joomla while transferred one host to another

Tags: mysql, joomla, phpmyadmin, fatal-error

I transferred all the files and database and installed in a new **cpanel** but after that that error showing. I setup all in **configuration.php** file too. Don't know how to fix it.

Error displaying the error page:

```
Application Instantiation Error: Table 'dnccgov_city.xjnuq_session'
doesn't exist SQL=DELETE FROM `xjnuq_session` WHERE `time` < '1464248273'
```

Comment: In cases like this, it's best to start by Googling parts of the error message. It turns up e.g. this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166607/migrated-joomla-site-shows-table-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 0):

Table :

> xjnuq_session

in Databse:

> dnccgov_city

dosent exists! Just check your DB for the table (it seems you missing to copy it). The error easily told you that the table dosent exist

Check also your configuration.php if the "dbprefix" match the new db prefix!

joomla is currently looking in Database named "dnccgov_city" for a table called "xjnuq_session". Check if both exists (DB and table).